# how to show all image data on carousel using ngFor angular 7

Tags: angular, carousel, ngfor

i have carousel that will display 3 image on once slide. on ts file i already get image from htb. the code is below. anyway, when i console.log the image, it show all image data (4 image).

```
this.htbservicesService.getHtb()
            .subscribe( 
                htbs => {
                   this.htbs = htbs

                    for(var i = 0; i < htbs.length; i++) {
                    var obj = htbs[i];
                    console.log(obj.image);

                    this.imageObject = [{
                        image: obj.image,
                        thumbImage: obj.image   
                     }];
                    }       
              },
                error => reject(error),
                () => resolve("good")
            );
        });
```

and on html file only display 1 images from images that already looped. the html for display image is below

```
<ng-image-slider [images]="imageObject" #nav></ng-image-slider>
```

i have tried to loop on view page (html) like this. but nothing showed.

```
 <div *ngFor="let htb of imageObject">
    <ng-image-slider [images]="htb" #nav></ng-image-slider>
 <div>
```

the question is, how to show all image on carrousel? did I miss something or what should i do?

Comment: Soni, [images] must be an array of object, each of them with a propertie "image" or "video", so you must has an unique `<ng-image-sider>` but [images] must be `[images]="htbs"` (you can use use "map" to transform your array)

Comment: could you show me how to mapping the array?

Answer (score 0):

When you start your http call to retrieve the images, it seems to me like you are already receiving an array of a data structure containing an image. You could implement it like so:

```
unsubscribe: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
images = [];

ngOnInit() {
this.htbservicesService.getHtb()
.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)) // unsubscribes your observable on destroy of the component to prevent memory leak
            .subscribe( 
                htbs => {
                   this.images = htbs;                   }
            );
        });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.unsubscribe.next(true);
  this.unsubscribe.complete();
}
```

htbs needs to be a datastructure, thats looking like that:

```
    {
        image: 'assets/img/slider/1.jpg',
        thumbImage: 'assets/img/slider/1_min.jpeg',
        alt: 'alt of image',
        title: 'title of image'
    }
```

And in your html template:

```
<ng-image-slider *ngIf="images.length > 0" [images]="images" #nav></ng-image-slider>
```

You could use *ngIf to only show images if there are more than 0.

Kind regards

Comment: when i console.log, yes it shown all the data array value

Comment: @sagat, Are you sure? I think that this carousel need an array of object like, e.g. [{image:'uno.jpg},{image:'dos.jpg}]... see the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-image-slider

Comment: yes. this carousel need an array like that. that's why my code above use looping to image

Comment: I edited the answer. Sorry didt check for the datastructure before. If it stikll doesnt work I might add a stackblitz for you.